# how to map only if destination object doesn't have a value in Automapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have a mapper in place and I need to perform a conditional mapping, Condition is, map the value from source to destination only if the destination property value is null. How would I do that?

```
.ForMember(o => o.EmployeeId, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u.EmployeeId))
```

I want to assign value to EmployeeId only if it does't have a value already.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/v9.0.0/Conditional-mapping.html

Comment: Thanks Lucian for response, I did go through this documentation before posting here, in documentation and all the other places I only found a way to put condition on source property not on destination property.

Comment: There are many `Condition/PreCondition` overloads. You just have to find the right one.

Comment: Yes and all those methods work only on source object property. I did find a way of writing it on destination object property.

Comment: You get the destination object.

Answer (score 2):

The method of `IMemberConfigurationExpression` `.MapFrom()` has the overload that takes an IDestination `void MapFrom<TResult>(Func<TSource, TDestination, TResult> mappingFunction);` In your mapping function you can check the destination object.

Example:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.EmployeeId, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest) => dest ?? src.EmployeeId))
```